# Postgres json aggregate function calls cannot be nested

Tags: postgresql

I have this select statement, I want to export them to json array with an another nested json agregate function but postgres says that "aggregate function calls cannot be nested", I can not figure aout how i can do this.

```
select json_agg(json_build_object(
        'plan_number', plan.id,
        'plan_carrier_code', carrier_plan.carrier_code,
        'plan_name', plan.plan_name,
        'plan_mac', mac.mac_name,
        'plan_termination_date', plan.termination_date,
        'plan_mod_start_date', plan.mod_start_date,
        'plan_mod_user', plan.mod_user,
        'plan_opt_brandcode_g_on_mn_as_generic_copay', plan.opt_brandcode_g_on_mn_as_generic_copay, 
        'plan_opt_exclude_daw2_from_ded_calculations', plan.opt_exclude_daw2_from_ded_calculations,
        'plan_opt_exclude_daw2_from_oop_calculations', plan.opt_exclude_daw2_from_oop_calculations,
        'plan_opt_limit_patient_pay_to_pay', plan.opt_limit_patient_pay_to_pay, 
        'plan_opt_only_pay_primary_claims', plan.opt_only_pay_primary_claims,
        'plan_opt_allow_discontinued_drugs', plan.opt_allow_discontinued_drugs,
        'plan_opt_allow_negative_payments_to_pharmacy', plan.opt_allow_negative_payments_to_pharmacy,   
        'plan_opt_process_y_drugs_as_preferred', plan.opt_process_y_drugs_as_preferred,
        'plan_opt_reject_otc', plan.opt_reject_otc,
        'plan_opt_reject_repackaged_drugs', plan.opt_reject_repackaged_drugs,   
        'plan_opt_test_only', plan.opt_test_only,
        'plan_opt_cost_effective_pricing', plan.opt_cost_effective_pricing,
        'plan_opt_original_mony_for_copay', plan.opt_original_mony_for_copay,
        'plan_daw_differential', json_agg(json_build_object(
            'plan_daw_differential_daw_code', plan_daw_differential.daw_code,
            'plan_daw_differential_claim_type', plan_daw_differential.claim_type,
            'plan_daw_differential_updated_at', plan_daw_differential.updated_at,
            'plan_daw_differential_updated_by', plan_daw_differential.updated_by
        ))
    )) as plan
from splan.groups_plan_list gpl
left join splan.plan plan on plan.id = gpl.plan_id
left join splan.carrier carrier_plan on carrier_plan.id = plan.carrier_id
left join splan.plan_daw_differential plan_daw_differential on plan_daw_differential.parent_id = plan.id
left join sdrug.mac mac on mac.id = plan.mac_id
where gpl.parent_id = 69;
```

but it throws me an error that said "aggregate function calls cannot be nested"

the expected result can be:

```
[
   {
      "plan_number":1,
      "plan_carrier_code":"lltest",
      "plan_daw_differential":[
         {
            "plan_daw_differential_daw_code":"0505",
            "plan_daw_differential_claim_type":"02"
         },
         {
            "plan_daw_differential_daw_code":"0505",
            "plan_daw_differential_claim_type":"02"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Options:

1. use subquery (or join lateral) to evaluate `plan_daw_differential` element for every plan element.
2. using `GROUP BY plan... gpl... carrier_plan... mac...`

Because the solutions differ in execution plan you will have to pick one that fits your requirements the most.
I would go with first option in most cases. It is more compact easier to write and maintain. The only reason to pick the second would be requirement to filter the plan using data from `plan_daw_differential` table.

## Examples:

Subquery:

```
select json_agg(json_build_object(
        'plan_number', plan.id,
        'plan_carrier_code', carrier_plan.carrier_code,
        'plan_name', plan.plan_name,
        'plan_mac', mac.mac_name,
        'plan_termination_date', plan.termination_date,
        'plan_mod_start_date', plan.mod_start_date,
        'plan_mod_user', plan.mod_user,
        'plan_opt_brandcode_g_on_mn_as_generic_copay', plan.opt_brandcode_g_on_mn_as_generic_copay, 
        'plan_opt_exclude_daw2_from_ded_calculations', plan.opt_exclude_daw2_from_ded_calculations,
        'plan_opt_exclude_daw2_from_oop_calculations', plan.opt_exclude_daw2_from_oop_calculations,
        'plan_opt_limit_patient_pay_to_pay', plan.opt_limit_patient_pay_to_pay, 
        'plan_opt_only_pay_primary_claims', plan.opt_only_pay_primary_claims,
        'plan_opt_allow_discontinued_drugs', plan.opt_allow_discontinued_drugs,
        'plan_opt_allow_negative_payments_to_pharmacy', plan.opt_allow_negative_payments_to_pharmacy,   
        'plan_opt_process_y_drugs_as_preferred', plan.opt_process_y_drugs_as_preferred,
        'plan_opt_reject_otc', plan.opt_reject_otc,
        'plan_opt_reject_repackaged_drugs', plan.opt_reject_repackaged_drugs,   
        'plan_opt_test_only', plan.opt_test_only,
        'plan_opt_cost_effective_pricing', plan.opt_cost_effective_pricing,
        'plan_opt_original_mony_for_copay', plan.opt_original_mony_for_copay,
        'plan_daw_differential', ( 
           SELECT
             json_agg(json_build_object(
               'plan_daw_differential_daw_code', plan_daw_differential.daw_code,
               'plan_daw_differential_claim_type', plan_daw_differential.claim_type,
               'plan_daw_differential_updated_at', plan_daw_differential.updated_at,
               'plan_daw_differential_updated_by', plan_daw_differential.updated_by
              ))
           FROM
             splan.plan_daw_differential plan_daw_differential 
           WHERE
             plan_daw_differential.parent_id = plan.id )
    )) as plan
from 
  splan.groups_plan_list gpl
  left join splan.plan plan on plan.id = gpl.plan_id
  left join splan.carrier carrier_plan on carrier_plan.id = plan.carrier_id
  left join sdrug.mac mac on mac.id = plan.mac_id
where
  gpl.parent_id = 69;
```

Grouping:

```
select json_agg(json_build_object(
        'plan_number', plan_number,
        'plan_carrier_code', plan_carrier_code,
        'plan_name', plan_name,
        'plan_mac', plan_mac,
        'plan_termination_date', plan_termination_date,
        'plan_mod_start_date', plan_mod_start_date,
        'plan_mod_user', plan_mod_user,
        'plan_opt_brandcode_g_on_mn_as_generic_copay', plan_opt_brandcode_g_on_mn_as_generic_copay,
        'plan_opt_exclude_daw2_from_ded_calculations', plan_opt_exclude_daw2_from_ded_calculations,
        'plan_opt_exclude_daw2_from_oop_calculations', plan_opt_exclude_daw2_from_oop_calculations,
        'plan_opt_limit_patient_pay_to_pay', plan_opt_limit_patient_pay_to_pay,
        'plan_opt_only_pay_primary_claims', plan_opt_only_pay_primary_claims,
        'plan_opt_allow_discontinued_drugs', plan_opt_allow_discontinued_drugs,
        'plan_opt_allow_negative_payments_to_pharmacy', plan_opt_allow_negative_payments_to_pharmacy,
        'plan_opt_process_y_drugs_as_preferred', plan_opt_process_y_drugs_as_preferred,
        'plan_opt_reject_otc', plan_opt_reject_otc,
        'plan_opt_reject_repackaged_drugs', plan_opt_reject_repackaged_drugs,
        'plan_opt_test_only', plan_opt_test_only,
        'plan_opt_cost_effective_pricing', plan_opt_cost_effective_pricing,
        'plan_opt_original_mony_for_copay', plan_opt_original_mony_for_copay,
        'plan_daw_differential', draw_differential_arr
    )) as plan
FROM (
  SELECT
    plan.id AS plan_number,
    carrier_plan.carrier_code AS plan_carrier_code,
    plan.plan_name AS plan_name,
    mac.mac_name AS plan_mac,
    plan.termination_date AS plan_termination_date,
    plan.mod_start_date AS plan_mod_start_date,
    plan.mod_user AS plan_mod_user,
    plan.opt_brandcode_g_on_mn_as_generic_copay AS plan_opt_brandcode_g_on_mn_as_generic_copay,
    plan.opt_exclude_daw2_from_ded_calculations AS plan_opt_exclude_daw2_from_ded_calculations,
    plan.opt_exclude_daw2_from_oop_calculations AS plan_opt_exclude_daw2_from_oop_calculations,
    plan.opt_limit_patient_pay_to_pay AS plan_opt_limit_patient_pay_to_pay,
    plan.opt_only_pay_primary_claims AS plan_opt_only_pay_primary_claims,
    plan.opt_allow_discontinued_drugs AS plan_opt_allow_discontinued_drugs,
    plan.opt_allow_negative_payments_to_pharmacy AS plan_opt_allow_negative_payments_to_pharmacy,
    plan.opt_process_y_drugs_as_preferred AS plan_opt_process_y_drugs_as_preferred,
    plan.opt_reject_otc AS plan_opt_reject_otc,
    plan.opt_reject_repackaged_drugs AS plan_opt_reject_repackaged_drugs,
    plan.opt_test_only AS plan_opt_test_only,
    plan.opt_cost_effective_pricing AS plan_opt_cost_effective_pricing,
    plan.opt_original_mony_for_copay AS plan_opt_original_mony_for_copay,
    json_agg(json_build_object(
            'plan_daw_differential_daw_code', plan_daw_differential.daw_code,
            'plan_daw_differential_claim_type', plan_daw_differential.claim_type,
            'plan_daw_differential_updated_at', plan_daw_differential.updated_at,
            'plan_daw_differential_updated_by', plan_daw_differential.updated_by
        )) as draw_differential_arr
  FROM
    splan.groups_plan_list gpl
    left join splan.plan plan on plan.id = gpl.plan_id
    left join splan.carrier carrier_plan on carrier_plan.id = plan.carrier_id
    left join splan.plan_daw_differential plan_daw_differential on plan_daw_differential.parent_id = plan.id
    left join sdrug.mac mac on mac.id = plan.mac_id
  WHERE
    gpl.parent_id = 69
  GROUP BY
    plan.id,
    carrier_plan.carrier_code,
    plan.plan_name,
    mac.mac_name,
    plan.termination_date,
    plan.mod_start_date,
    plan.mod_user,
    plan.opt_brandcode_g_on_mn_as_generic_copay,
    plan.opt_exclude_daw2_from_ded_calculations,
    plan.opt_exclude_daw2_from_oop_calculations,
    plan.opt_limit_patient_pay_to_pay,
    plan.opt_only_pay_primary_claims,
    plan.opt_allow_discontinued_drugs,
    plan.opt_allow_negative_payments_to_pharmacy,
    plan.opt_process_y_drugs_as_preferred,
    plan.opt_reject_otc,
    plan.opt_reject_repackaged_drugs,
    plan.opt_test_only,
    plan.opt_cost_effective_pricing,
    plan.opt_original_mony_for_copay
) AS plan_row
```